# Undeclared Identifier error in C although it is Declared

Tags: c, cs50

Iam a beginner in C and I was writing a program it's giving an error of undeclared identifier although it is identified and also some other errors for example "expression is not assignable". Please check the errors:

```
4 errors generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'reads' failed
make: *** [reads] Error 1
~/pset2/readability/ $ make practice
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    practice.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o practice
~/pset2/readability/ $ make reads
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    reads.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o reads
reads.c:16:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'n'
    for (i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
                ^
reads.c:16:36: error: use of undeclared identifier 'n'
    for (i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
                                   ^
reads.c:21:32: error: expression is not assignable
    if ((isspace(s[i]) || s[i] = ('"')) && (s[i+1]))
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
3 errors generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'reads' failed
make: *** [reads] Error 1
```

This is the program I have written what I feel is something is wrong on some other lines and I am unable to identify any help would be appreciated.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    string s = get_string("Text: ");
    int countletters = 0; int countwords = 0; int countsentences = 0; int i = 0; /* int n; -- added by OP after the question was asked */
    if(isalpha(s[0]))
    {
        countwords++;
    }
  for (i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
    if(isalpha(s[i]))
    {
        countletters++;
    }
    if ((isspace(s[i]) || s[i] = ('"')) && (s[i+1]))
    {
        countwords++;
    }
    if (s[i]=='.' || s[i]=='!' || s[i] == '?')
    {
        countsentences++;
    }
    float L = (float)countletters / (float)countwords * 100 , S = (float)countsentences / (float)countwords * 100;
    float index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;
    if (index > 1)
    {
        printf("Grade is before 1 \n");
    }
    else if (index >= 16)
    {
        printf("Grade is 16+");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n",(int)round(index));
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was edited to add a declaration `int n;` (now marked by a comment ), rendering the whole question moot because the variable is now defined.  You should not edit your question to invalidate the whole question.  You could delete the question.

Comment: Note that the body of the first `for` loop is just the one `if (isalpha(s[i]))` statement.  The following two `if` statements are not part of the loop.  The third error is for `if ((isspace(s[i]) || s[i] = ('"')) && (s[i+1]))`; you probably intended `==` in place of the single `=` (assignment).

Answer (score 1):

You never declare n. Variables must be declared before assignment. You also seem to have several other compile time errors

Comment: Can you please tell me what is compile-time errrors?

Comment: Compile time errors are errors that are thrown when you try to compile your program. Essentially your code is not correct in some way. As I've mentioned, you never declare n. Your compiler also tells you that an expression is not assignable. Hint, look up the difference between assignment and an equality check.

Comment: Note, your title says you declared the variable. You did not. You must specify a type when declaring variables. You never specified ns type.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help sir

Comment: now when I declared n it's showing me an error of undeclared identifier of S and L but writing float before these two are not enough?

Comment: The same happened to the" i "but I declared it anyway above and removed "int" from for loop before "I" that's why i have written a title like this.

Comment: i have updated the equals to sign also it works thank you so much sir

Comment: Np. If there are still errors also post the new errors pls.

Comment: There are no new errors program works thank you so much for your help have a good day.